# Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, clr

I have an SQL Function that takes a String, a DATE and another string.

```
 EXEC  dbo.ReplaceString 'You ve been subscribed to the ##company## newsletter.',
NOW,'BIG DEES'  


CREATE Function [dbo].[ReplaceString]
(
            @main_message As Varchar(500), 
            @date_sent As DateTime, 
            @company As Varchar(30)

)
RETURNS VARCHAR(650)
AS 
BEGIN 


         RETURN(@main_message)

 END
```

Problem is when I try to execute this function, even after commenting out all code processing logic in my function, I get the error

**Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.**

I am not doing any data access of any kind in the function. All I have is code to process the string using the other information passed in.Anyone have an idea of what this problem could be from and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189915.aspx

```
-- Try to use a function as a parameter value.
-- This produces an error message.
EXEC dbo.uspGetWhereUsedProductID 819, GETDATE();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetDate()` instead of `NOW`

**Update I just notice you said DATE not DATETIME so try**

convert(date, GetDate())

Comment: I changed from GETDATE() to NOW thinking that would help but did not